# I am not getting this in binomial?

Tags: binomial-theorem

No ways to arrange ABC by using C(3,2) is AB BC AC . Not BA CB OR CA including.

When we solve $(a+b)^2$

a^2 + b^2 + 2ab

Is it that no ways to arrange for the 3rd term since it would be C(2,1) . it is no ways to arrange them would be ab or ba.
How do we write this here then?

[image]

Comment: ${3 \choose 2}$ is *not* the number of ways to arrange $A,B,C$.  ${3\choose 2}$ is the number of ways to choose two elements from $A,B,C$.  And the three ways are: 1) The two elements you choose are $A, B$. 2) the two things you choose are $A,C$ or 3) the two things you choose are $B,C$.  Notice that choosing $A$ and $B$ are the exact same two things ac choosing $B$ and $A$.... The number of ways to *arrange* $A,B,C$ are $3!=6$.  The six ways to arrange are i)$ABC$, ii) $ACB$, iii) $BAC$, iv) $BCA$, v) $CAB$, vi) $CBA$.  The number of ways to choose two items is a *completely* different quest.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,  I see what your book is getting at.

${3\choose 2}$ is the coefficient of $ab^2$.  That is *one* $a$ and *two* $b$s.  So you need the number of ways to arrange $a,b,b$.  They are not three *different* things.

There are three ways to do it.   they are 1) $a,b,b$ and 2) $b,a,b$ and 3) $b,b,a$.

There are two ways to think of ${3\choose 2}$.  It can be thought of as the number of ways to pick two items out of three different items. (That's how I think of it and that is why the operation is call "$3$ *CHOOSE* $2$).  But you book is thinking of it as: how many ways are there to arrange two different types of items if you have $2$ of one type, and the remaining out of $3$ items are all the second type.

Those two ways of thinking are equivalent because if you think of it the second way, all you are really doing is choosing $2$ out of three positions to place the first type of item.

=========

${3 \choose 2}$ is *not* the number of ways to arrange $A,B,C$.

${3\choose 2}$ is the number of ways to choose two elements from $A,B,C$.  And the three ways are: 1) The two elements you choose are $A, B$. 2) the two things you choose are $A,C$ or 3) the two things you choose are $B,C$.  Notice that choosing $A$ and $B$ are the exact same two things as choosing $B$ and $A$....

The number of ways to *arrange* $A,B,C$ are $3!=6$.  The six ways to arrange are i)$ABC$, ii) $ACB$, iii) $BAC$, iv) $BCA$, v) $CAB$, vi) $CBA$.  The number of ways to choose two items is a *completely* different question.

${2\choose 1}=2$ is the number of ways  to choose *ONE* item from two.  So the number of ways to choose one item from $A,B$ are two ways,  1) You can choose $A$, or 2) You can choose $B$.  Those are the only two ways to choose one item from $A,B$.

=============

The binomial Thereom states if you expand out $(a + b)^k$ you will get a sum with $k+1$ terms and the coefficient the $j$th term will be ${k\choose j-1}$.

So the three terms when you expand $(a+b)^2$ will be $a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ (note the order of the coefficients).  The first coefficient of the $a^2$ term will be ${2\choose 0} = 1$.  There is *one* way to choose $0$ items from $2$ items that one way is to choose no items.

The second coefficient of the $ab$ term will be ${2\choose 1} = 2$.  There are $2$ ways  to choose one item from $2$ items. (You can chose one... or the other).

And the third coefficient of the $b^2$ term will be ${2\choose 2} = 1$.  There is $1$ way to choose two items from $2$ items.  That one and only way is to choose both the items.

So if we expand $(a+b)^2$ we get $(a+b)^2 = {2\choose 0}a^2 + {2\choose 1}ab + {2\choose 2}b^2 = 1\cdot a^2 + 2\cdot ab + 1\cdot b^2 = a^2 + 2ab +b^2$.

And if we expand $(a+b)^3$ we get $(a+b)^3 = {3\choose 0}a^3 + {3\choose 1}a^2b + {3\choose 2}ab^2 + {3\choose 3}b^3 = 1a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + 1b^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3$.

Do you see why ${3\choose 0} = 1$?  The only $1$ way to choose zero items is not to choose any.

Do you see why ${3\choose 1} =3$.  The  $3$ ways to choose one item, is to choose one item, and there are three to choose from.

Do you see why ${3\choose 2} =3$?  There are three pairs we can choose.

Do you see why ${3\choose 3} =1$?  The $1$ way to choose three items is to choose all of them.

Comment: pls check edit.

Comment: Do you mean to say that my book states that at 1st position , no of ways x and y can be chosen.xy or yx.Once they are chosen , then there is only one. That

Comment: Way to choose them since one of them is at 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the third term, $2ab$ stems from the fact that the # of ways of secting one element from a choice of 2 is $\binom{2}{1} = \frac{2!}{1!\times(2-1)!} = 2.$

Write down $(a + b)$.

Directly below it, write down $(a + b)$ again.

When you manually multiply it out, you see that the $2ab$ term comes from :

First you select one of the $a$'s from either the first or second line.

Once that $a$ is chosen, considering that you are focusing on the $2ab$ term, you will then choose the $b$ from the other line.

For a clearer understanding of why combinations rather than permutations are involved, perform the same manual computation of $(a + b)^3$ by writing $(a + b)$ on three separate lines, and work through the multiplication.

For example, the $3a^2b$ term will arise because there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of choosing which 2 of the 3 lines, you will select the $a$ factor from.  Then, each selection of 2 $a$'s and 1 $b$ results in a $a^2 b$ product.

In fact, this type of analysis can be construed to be a demonstration of the binomial theorem, re for $n \in \mathbb{Z^+},$

$$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^k b^{(n-k)}.$$

The binomial theorem can alternatively be demonstrated through straight algebra, based on the idea that

$$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n + 1}{k + 1}.$$

**Addendum** 
Responding to the OP's request to re-check his query.

The image shown matches the binomial theorem.

> Is it that no ways to arrange for the 3rd term since it would be C(2,1) . it is no ways to arrange them would be ab or ba.

If this is your question, then **no**.  This is the **wrong** way to consider it.  The easiest way to demonstrate how you calculate the coefficient of each term in the binomial expansion is to consider $(a + b)^4$, which can be represented as

$(a + b) ~\times$ 
$(a + b) ~\times$ 
$(a + b) ~\times$ 
$(a + b).$

Consider the terms:

$(a^4)$
There are $\binom{4}{4}$ ways of choosing 4 $a$'s from the 4 factors above.

$(a^3b)$ 
There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of choosing 3 $a$'s from the factors above.

$(a^2b^2)$ 
There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of choosing 2 $a$'s from the factors above.

$(ab^3)$ 
There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways of choosing 1 $a$ from the factors above.

$(b^4)$ 
There are $\binom{4}{0}$ ways of choosing 0 $a$'s from the factors above.

**Addendum-1**
Responding to the OP's last comment.

> If there 2 a’s , then there are also 2b’s.That means no of ways to arrange them is $\frac{4!}{2!}{2!}.$

Okay, now, I see what you are saying.  Instead of focusing on the fact that in the Addendum multiplication, you were choosing 2 of the 4 $a$'s, you are focusing on the fact that if you have 2$a$'s and 2$b$'s and 4 **slots** to drop them in, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of choosing which slots to assign to the $a$'s.

There is a **bijection** between arranging the 2$a$'s and 2$b$'s into 4 slots on the one hand, and choosing which of the 4 factors will contribute the 2$a$'s on the other hand.

Therefore, if I have understood you correctly, **yes**, you can explain the coefficient of any term $a^kb^{(n-k)}$ by asking how many ways can you select $k$ slots out of $n$ to position the k$a$'s.

Comment: Pls check my edit.

Comment: @user279337 See my addendum.  I wasn't sure what you are asking.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: According to my book as well.In your addendum. If there 2 a’s , then there are also 2b’s.That means no of ways to arrange them is $\frac{4!}{2!*2!}.$

Comment: @user279337 See my Edit-1 section.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your addition edit here is a second answer:

It is misleading and unfortunate that the text used "arrangement".  I believe a better (albeit semantically confusing and challenging) way of saying it would be "choices to position 2 out 3 items".

The coefficient of the $ab^2$ term in $(a+b)^3$ is ${3\choose 2} = 3$ is *not* because we are arranging $2$ out of three different objects, but instead it is because we are *choosing* out of $3$ copies of $b$ we are picking $2$ of them.

.....

Bear with me.

When we have $(a+b)^k$ we have $k$ copies of the pair $a,b$.  (I'll illustrate with color)

$$(a+b)^k = \color{blue}{(a+b)}\color{red}{(a+b)}\color{green}{(a+b)}\color{orange}{(a+b)}$$

When we expand that out we will pick one $a$ or $b$ from each pair to get $2^k$ terms:

$$ \color{blue}{(a+b)}\color{red}{(a+b)}\color{green}{(a+b)}\color{orange}{(a+b)}=\\ \color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\\ \color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\\ \color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\\ \color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}b$$

Now as a term with $m$ $b$s (and the remaining $k-m$ all being $a$s) are all the same and it doesn't matter which of the $k$ choices the $m$ $b$s came from we can combine then.

So the coefficient of the $a^{k-m}b^m$ will be the number of ways that, out of $k$ total copies of our $b$s, we can chose $m$ of them.

Let's draw a picture (For the picture I'll have to acknowledge I'm using $k = 4$).

$$\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\\ \color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\\ \color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\\ \color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}b=$$

[Ways to have $0$ $b$s:]  $\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}a+$  [(${4\choose 0}=1$ ways to do it]

[Ways to have $1$ $b$:]  $\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}a+$ [(${4\choose 1}=4$ ways to do it]

[Ways to have $2$ $b$s:]  $\color{blue}a\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}a+$ [(${4\choose 2}=6$ ways to do it]

[Ways to have $3$ $b$s:]  $\color{blue}a\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}a\color{green}b\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}a\color{orange}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}a+$ [(${4\choose 3}=4$ ways to do it]

[Ways to have $4$ $b$s:]  $\color{blue}b\color{red}b\color{green}b\color{orange}b=$  [(${4\choose 4}=1$ ways to do it]

$${4\choose 0}a^4 + {4\choose 1}a^3b + {4\choose 2}a^2b^2 + {4\choose 1}a^3b + {4\choose 0}b^4=\\ a^4 + 4a^3b+ 6a^2b^2 + 4ab^3 +b^4$$.

And that's the binomial theorem!

......

so $$(a+b)^2 =\\\color{blue}{(a+b)}\color{red}{(a+b)}=\\\color{blue}a\color{red}a+\color{blue}a\color{red}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}a+\color{blue}b\color{red}b=\\\color{blue}a\color{red}a + \color{blue}b\color{red}b + (\color{blue}a\color{red}b+\color{blue}b\color{red}a)=\\a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$

====

P.S.  Neat little fact that comes out of all this meshugana is that ${n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + {n\choose 2} + ....... +{n\choose n-1} + {n\choose n} = 2^n$.

Who would have thunk it?!